# ADF Faces custom component and javascript function

Tags: javascript, oracle11g, oracle-adf

I'm using the ADF Faces librairies and made a custom component that display a graph using d3js.  In that component I import lot of javascript code that I wrote in separate js files.  There is js code for handling buttons' click event.  My component is displaying fine and behave the way I want except on button's click, where each time I click a button, my js function is well executed but after that all the page is reloaded.  How to prevent the page to reload on button's click ?

Buttons are created using javascript and d3js librairie

```
zoomPanel.selectAll("button").data([zoom1, zoom2, zoom3]).enter().append("button");
buttons = zoomPanel.selectAll("button");
buttons
                .attr("id", function(zp) {
                    return zp.id;
                })
                .attr("class", "btn btn-default")
                .text(function(zp) {
                    return zp.text;
                })
                .on("click", function(zp) {
                     zoomEvent(zp);
                });
```

Thank you.

**I found that I forgot to add the type attribute.  In my case by adding type button fixed the issue.**

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve your problem,but you could try setting the Partial-Submit property on the button (command-button not go-button) and it should prevent a page refresh. More [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/partial_submit_vs_auto_submit).

Comment: I could try that to see if it can help...But there is no way to tell ADF not to do anything on button click ?  I allready have my own javascript to handle the event.  All is handled client side by my javascript code.